# How to add annotations and remarks to the right side like this

Tags: two-column

[image]

This picture is from the Internet and I have no code to show my problem. So could you make a demo for me and show me how to add annotations in the proper positions. I think adjusting them to the proper positions is important and also difficult.

Comment: hope latexdiff may suits with your requirement....

Comment: You could also use the `changes` package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The highlighting and comments can be provided by `easyReview` However I suspect the source you are showing which has the reply feature was generated in a web CSS template.

The following are  not proper review uses just enough to let you visualise effects

You already do have the ability to add "Margin notes" as a mini paragraph already see where I inserted "The first major event"

There are odd occasions that does not work and you can add the `marginnote` package for similar usage see where I inserted "He lost it all"

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[11pt]{article} % use larger type; default would be 10pt
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % set input encoding (not needed with XeLaTeX)
%%% Examples of Article customizations
% These packages are optional, depending whether you want the features they provide.
% See the LaTeX Companion or other references for full information.
%%% PAGE DIMENSIONS
\usepackage{geometry} % to change the page dimensions
\geometry{a4paper} 
\usepackage{graphicx} % support the \includegraphics command and options
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} % Activate to begin paragraphs with an empty line rather than an indent
\usepackage{marginnote} % for better margin notes
\usepackage{easyReview}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}\textbf{A Famous Steve Jobs Speech Is Hidden on Your Mac}\end{center}

Every Mac which has the Pages app for OS X installed includes a little Easter Egg that few know about; a famous Steve Jobs speech, tucked away in a little unassuming folder. Technically, it’s two different Steve Jobs speeches, the famous text from the Crazy Ones Think Different campaign, and arguably the even more famous 2005 Steve Jobs commencement speech from Stanford University. 

The first paragraph is the classic text from the Think Different, “Here’s To The Crazy Ones” commercial, which debuted around 1997.  Full text of The Crazy Ones, which was apparently written by Steve Jobs, is as follows:

“Here’s to the crazy ones. The misfits, the rebels. The troublemakers. The round pegs in the square holes. The ones who see things differently. They’re not fond of rules. You can quote them, disagree with them, glorify or vilify them. About the only thing you can’t do is ignore them. Because they change things. They push the human race forward. And while some may see them as the crazy ones, we see genius. Because the ones who are crazy enough to think that they can change the world, are the ones who do.”

The Crazy Ones text also appears written on the icon for the TextEdit application.

\textbf{``My second story is about love and loss.''}\marginpar[hello]{This is the first major event} 

``I was lucky - I found what I loved to do early in life. \highlight{Woz and I started Apple in my parents garage when I was 20.} We worked hard, and in 10 years Apple had grown from just the two of us in a garage into a  2 billion dollar company with over 4000 employees. We had just released our finest creation — the Macintosh — a year earlier, and I had just turned 30. And then I got fired. How can you get fired from a company you started? Well, as Apple grew we hired someone who I thought was very talented to run the company with me, and for the first year or so things went well. \marginnote{He lost it all}But then our visions of the future began to diverge and eventually we had a falling out. When we did, our Board of Directors sided with him. So at 30 I was out. And very publicly out. What had been the focus of my entire adult life was gone, and it was devastating.

I really didn’t know what to do for a few months. I felt that I had let the previous generation of entrepreneurs down – that I had dropped the baton as it was being passed to me. I met with David Packard and Bob Noyce and tried to apologize for screwing up so badly. I was a very public failure, and I even thought about running away from the valley. But something slowly began to dawn on me — I still loved what I did. The turn of events at Apple had not changed that one bit. I had been rejected, but I was still in love. And so I decided to start over.''

\end{document}
```